# I am trying to test my dropdowns in form with cypress, it selects values but doesn't submit them (works manually)

Tags: reactjs, cypress, e2e-testing, react-select

This is the code :

```
  cy.get('.react-select-container')
    .first()
    .click();
  cy.get('.react-select__option')
    .eq(1)
    .click();
  cy.get('.react-select-container')
    .eq(1)
    .click();
  cy.get('.react-select__option')
    .eq(1)
    .click();
  cy.wait(500);
  cy.get('.react-select-container')
    .eq(2)
    .click();
  cy.get('.react-select__option')
    .eq(1)
    .click();
  cy.wait(1500);

  cy.get('.btn').click({ force: true });
  cy.wait('@backendReq')
    .its('response.statusCode')
    .should('eq', 200 || 201);
```

since it is not regular dropdown (select), I cant use .select(), but I simulate clicks, they are shown as selected  but when I submit form they are not submited

Comment: Can you share the code that is being tested here as well please? Otherwise it's hard to guess what might be wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
 cy.get('.react-select-container')
        .eq(3)
        .click()
        .find('input')
        .first()
        .type('novo{downArrow}{enter}', {
          force: true,
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try to use cypress' **invoke** method to change its `value` attribute if that's possible in the application you're testing.

```
const value = 'Option'  // The option you'll need to select on dropdown

cy.get('.react-select__option')
    .invoke('attr', 'value', value)
```

Alternatively consider cypress' **type** if the dropdown you're testing is an input (in this case you'll need to pass **force: true** as options).

```
const value = 'Option'  // The option you'll need to select on dropdown

cy.get('.react-select__option')
    .type(value, { force: true })
```

As an improvement, you can also replace your `wait` to asserts after the selection, so it would not continues before the selection successfully happen.

Something like this after **invoke** or **type**:

```
.should('have.value', value)
```